# Drupal 7 "Can't add fields to content type?"

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Drupal 7
I have a problem with adding more "fields" to my content type (node).

to explain it in details, I have contact type called "`staff`" with 17 fields.
I want to add more one field called "`Staff ID no`" after writing field name it is not taking me to next "field settings page" instead it keeps me in the same page!

When I try to add the field again it gave me the below error message"

```
"The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique."
```

which mean it is already been created from the first attempt but yet still not shown in "`staff`" content type fields area?

is there any limitation of fields quantity per content type?

Please advise?

Comment: There is no limit to the amount of fields on a content type. Check the page at `admin/reports/fields` and see if your field is listed and if it says it is attached to your staff content type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply, actually it is not listed in fields report page!

Comment: and BTW, I can add fields to other content types but not this one "staff" !?

Comment: Probably Drupal messed up something while you were creating that field for the first time. Try finding it in database and deleting it directly there...

Comment: But I tried to add another 5 fields and still can't find them?!

Comment: By the way, how do i locate the missing field in DB and delete it?

Answer (score 0):

`"The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique."`this error occour when a field with same machine name exist.suppose u have field named Staff ID and it created with machine name `staff_id` and then u have another field with name Staff IDs and you r saving it's machine name as `staff_id` it will show that error.if u save it with `staff_ids`.it will save.